# Yum commands cheat sheet for Macports users

Tags: linux, package-management, macports, yum

What are the equivalent `yum` commands of the following MacPorts `port` commands?

- search
- self-update
- installed (list)
- outdated  (list)

Are some things completely different from MacPorts?

Comment: I wonder if I mentioned that I need this knowledge to manage a pair of CentOS servers, the question would not have been migrated. Not that I care.

Comment: You're lucky it didn't get deleted for having "can haz" in the title. Very unprofessional.

Answer (score 7):

For the specific commands you listed (in order)....

- yum search
- yum upgrade yum
- yum list installed
- yum list updates or yum check-update

For any others, I would recommend reading the man page.  It is very well written, and contains a lot more information.

The biggest differences you will probably notice are:

1. Installs will happen much faster since the packages do not have to be compiled
2. You will be presented a list of every package that will be installed (including dependencies) for review before the install actually happens.